# Javascript: how to place paramenters in function when using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

how can I use parameters in functions when adding them to an element? I tried this:

```
first.addEventListener("click", Bold(this, true));
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: wrap it in an anonymous function

Comment: Within the function `Bold()`, `this` will already refer to the `first` element/node so that's unnecessary (though of course you still have the issue of how to pass `true`, or any other argument).

Comment: @Pointy how do I do that?

Comment: `first.addEventListener("click", function (e) { Bold(e.target, true); });` (within the anonymous function, I'm not sure if `this` refers to the `first` element/node or if it's the `Window`/global-object, so here I used `e.target` rather than `this`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note - I assume by this

```
Bold(this, true)
```

you want Bold called with your current `this` as the `this` value?  If so the simplest way would be to use `bind`

```
first.addEventListener("click", Bold.bind(this, true)));
```

And if my assumption was wrong, and you don't care about `this` in Bold, and actually want your current `this` passed as the first parameter, then it would simply be

```
Bold.bind(null, this, true)
```

And finally I'll note that the above won't work on IE8, so you'd have to shim `bind` (example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) but hopefully you don't have to support archaic browsers like that.

---

EDIT

So you want the element you clicked to be `this` in your function.  This is probably the simplest solution

```
first.addEventListener("click", function(){ Bold.call(this, true); });
```

Comment: Be mindful of the `this` you're binding. ;-) ...oh, you mentioned that! It's too early here. :-)

Comment: It would be nice if `.bind()` let you only bind arguments, and leave `this` in its caller-defined state.

Comment: @quite - the fat arrow functions coming in ES6 will help quite a bit with that, since they have a lexically bound `this`. I believe this would work, but I could be wrong: `first.addEventListener("click", () => Bold.call(this, true)));`

Comment: Thanks, good to see you. I'm not here too often anymore... only when I'm feeling masochistic. :-D

Comment: And yeah, fat arrow functions will be nice, as will array comprehensions, though I understand they've been bumped to ES7.

Comment: Nice.  You know where to find me if you're ever looking for a good dev job on a Knockout-based SPA.  I can't hire you, but I can put in a good word.

Comment: Thanks, I've got that in the back of my mind, though I'm strongly considering a bright future in vagrancy. I hear it's the next big thing. :-)

Comment: @Fabio - start dropping `debugger;` statements and debug it!

Comment: @AdamRackis when using `first.addEventListener("click", Bold.bind(null, this, true));` it says that `this` is Window, when I want the element `first` to be the `this`

Comment: Then bind first as `this` -> `Bold.bind(first, true)`

Comment: Did it. Now the event works but when clicking the element, in the function Bold I get as parameters `true` and `MouseEvent`, and not `first` and `true`

Comment: @Fabio - so you want the element set to `this` *and also* passed as a parameter?  That doesn't make sense.  But if you really want it also passed, then just pass it.  `Bold.call(this, this, true)`

Comment: No I want `first` and `true` passed as parameters, but when the function `Bold` is called by the `click` event of `first`(at which we added the eventListener) it has as parameters `true` and `MouseEvent` instead of `first` and `true`. This is a mess sorry ahah

Comment: with `Bold.call(this, first, true)` works, but it executes the function when it adds the eventListener (I used `first.addEventListener("click", Bold.call(this, first, true));`) instead of the click

Comment: I finally got it:  `first.addEventListener("click", function(){ Bold.call(first, first, true); }); ` I don't know what the first  `first ` means but it works so it's ok ahah